# Is dropping an object on a hard drive as harmful as dropping it?

Tags: external-hard-drive, physical-damage

I have recently dropped a remote control on my enternal hard drive accidentally from like 20-30 centimeters distance. I wondered whether it might have been less harmful than dropping it from the same distance. It seems to work (for now at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mass of a hard drive is many levels greater than that of a remote control. The potential energy of the hard drive contributes to the deceleration of the drop, which would be transmitted to the moving parts of the drive, primarily the heads and actuator/positioning arms. Not all of the energy is going to go into the heads and arms, but enough that a drop may cause problems.

The remote control impacting the hard drive will impart far less force to the drive casing, causing less acceleration/deceleration and less internal movement as well.

I suspect you will have very little to zero problems from the scenario provided.